# parsing text file into array of objects

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, text-parsing

Hi I have text file looks like below.

```
operation=EAT
starttime=134662223
endtime=134665223
totaltime=3454
end
operation=DRINK
starttime=134662223
endtime=134665223
totaltime=34354
end
operation=SLEEP
starttime=134662223
endtime=134665223
totaltime=34543
end
operation=WALK
starttime=13463223
endtime=13466323
totaltime=66643344
end
```

I want to create array of objects of operations. I can write parsing logic. but i am worrying it may take more time. 
My object looks like below

```
class Operation
{
private String name;
private long startTime
private long endTime
private totalTime
//Getters and Setters
}
```

The above one is simple bean which has data of one operation.

How do I achieve this one ? any third party library helps me ?   The ultimate goal of this task is to convert the flat file into xml file in an organized form. like below.

```
<operation name=EAT>
  <starttime>13322444<starttime>
  <endtime>13323444<endtime>
  <totaltime>13322444<totaltime>
</operation>
<operation name=DRINK>
  <starttime>13322444<starttime>
  <endtime>13323444<endtime>
  <totaltime>13322444<totaltime>
</operation>
..
..
```

Please help me in doing this. Thanks for reading this. and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to do this, but a common method is to use one of the third party parsers which can do all the (un)marshaling of the xml structure. Or SAX is a good option: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/